# Eclipse Kepler making multiple SSH connections

Tags: eclipse, ssh, firewall

I'm working in 
Ubuntu 12.04,
Kepler-
   Version: Kepler Service Release 2
   Build id: 20140224-0627

I'm a little stuck as to why Kepler seems to be making a huge amount of SSH connections to my CVS server perform some fairly basic tasks- say syncing with repository over a fairly large folder.

I've run `netstat -nputwc | grep "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx"` (my server IP with CVS repository on it) and it brings up sometimes a few, sometimes a huge amount of seperate connections...

I've put in below the print out I get, in this particular case Eclipse made so many the firewall for my server was triggered and I was locked out...

I've replaced multiple TIME_WAITs with '...' and had to cut off the end even though there was a lot more to keep in SOF work limit... Sorry for the huge print out but really stuck here!!

Any help would be brilliant, thanks for reading

John

```
xxxxx@demo:~$ sudo netstat -nputwc | grep "(repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx"

tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55746   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 29943/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55747   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 29949/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55746   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 29943/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55747   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    29956/ssh
tcp     4344      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55746   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 29943/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55747   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 29956/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55746   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 29943/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55749   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 29963/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55747   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55749   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55747   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55750   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 29970/ssh
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55747   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55751   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 29976/ssh
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55751   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55753   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 29982/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55750   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55754   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 29988/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55749   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55747   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55751   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55750   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55755   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 29994/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55754   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55754   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55759   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30000/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55749   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55754   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55760   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30006/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55759   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55750   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55761   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30012/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55747   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55762   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30018/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55751   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55761   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55763   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30024/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55762   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55764   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30030/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55751   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55765   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30036/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55754   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55759   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55766   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30042/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55749   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
..
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55754   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55767   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30048/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55760   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55751   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55768   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30054/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55750   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55759   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55769   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30060/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55766   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30066/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55765   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30066/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55765   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30066/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55765   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30066/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55765   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30066/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55765   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30066/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55765   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30066/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55765   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30066/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55765   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30066/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55765   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30066/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55765   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30066/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55765   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30066/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55765   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
..
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30066/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55765   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30066/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55765   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
....
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30066/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55765   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30066/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55765   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30066/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55765   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30066/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55765   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
..
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30066/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55765   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30066/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55765   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30066/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55765   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30066/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55765   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30066/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55765   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30066/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55765   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30066/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55765   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30066/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55765   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30066/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55765   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55748   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30066/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55765   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
...
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55769   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30066/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55769   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       ESTABLISHED 30066/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55779   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30073/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55779   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30073/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55779   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30073/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55779   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30073/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55779   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30073/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55779   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30073/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55779   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30073/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55779   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30073/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55779   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30073/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55779   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30073/ssh          (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55779   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30073/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55779   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30073/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55779   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30073/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55779   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30073/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55779   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30073/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55781   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30079/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55781   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30079/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55781   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30079/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55781   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30079/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55781   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30079/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55781   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30079/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55781   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30079/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55781   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30079/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55781   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30079/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55781   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30079/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55781   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30079/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55781   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30079/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55781   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30079/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55781   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30079/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55781   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30079/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55781   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30079/ssh
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      0 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55774   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       FIN_WAIT2   -
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55783   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30085/ssh
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55783   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30085/ssh
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55783   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30085/ssh
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55783   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30085/ssh
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55783   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30085/ssh
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55783   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30085/ssh
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55783   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30085/ssh
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55783   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30085/ssh
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55783   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30085/ssh
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55783   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30085/ssh
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55783   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30085/ssh
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55783   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30085/ssh
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55783   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30085/ssh
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55783   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30085/ssh
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55783   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30085/ssh
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55783   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30085/ssh
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55788   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30092/ssh
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55788   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30092/ssh
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55788   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30092/ssh
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55788   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30092/ssh
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55788   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30092/ssh
tcp        0      1 (myIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:55788   (repositoryIp)xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:port       SYN_SENT    30092/ssh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using SSH multiplexing

http://www.stremler.net/Code/cvs_tricks/cvs-over-ssh-advanced2.html

if Eclipse can use native SSH

Comment: Legend!! Cheers mate think that's sorted it.